# Cant work with for each

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string>
// Sequence containers
#include <list>
#include <vector>

int main() {
string sve[MAX] = { "one","two", "three", "four", "five" };
//2
vector <string> vstr;
//3
for(int i=0;i<MAX;i++)
    vstr.push_back(sve[i]);
//4
cout<<"---Vector---\n";
for each (string s in vstr)
    cout<<s<<endl;
```

error: expected "(" after for. the error occurs on the for each line

i dont think im missing any include, this is weird. im on xcode 4.3

Comment: Look up the syntax. This is quite different than the proper syntax. You also don't need that array to fill your vector.

Comment: `for each (string s in vstr)` is not valid syntax

Comment: `for each (type foo in bar)` is a [Microsoft extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177202%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Use the standard C++ `for (type foo : bar)` syntax instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax is wrong. Try this :

```
for(string s : vstr)
    cout<<s<<endl;
```

---

By the way, instead of initializing the array, and copying into vector, you can do it in one step, and skill the array creation :

```
std::vector<std::string> sve{ "one","two", "three", "four", "five" };
```

Answer (score 0):

Is is not valid C++ - Not compiling is the give away

Perhaps look into http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/ is what you are thinking of